# How to disable date before tomorrow in datepickerimpl?

Tags: java

I want to select only date from tomorrow. If today is 19 April 2020, I want to select date from 20 April 2020 and more. But nothing before.

I used this code:

```java
 public class DateLabelFormatter extends AbstractFormatter {

        private String datePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        public SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(datePattern);



        @Override
        public Object stringToValue(String text) throws ParseException {
            return dateFormatter.parseObject(text);
        }

        @Override
        public String valueToString(Object value) throws ParseException {
            if (value != null) {
                Calendar cal = (Calendar) value;
                return dateFormatter.format(cal.getTime());
            }

            return "";
        }


    }

model1 = new UtilDateModel();
p1 = new Properties();
p1.put("text.today", "Today");
p1.put("text.month", "Month");
p1.put("text.year", "Year");
datePanel1 = new JDatePanelImpl(model1, p1);
datePicker1 = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel1, new DateLabelFormatter());
```

Comment: model1 = new UtilDateModel();
            p1 = new Properties();
            p1.put("text.today", "Oggi");
            p1.put("text.month", "Mese");
            p1.put("text.year", "Anno");
            datePanel1 = new JDatePanelImpl(model1, p1);
            datePicker1 = new JDatePickerImpl(datePanel1, new DateLabelFormatter());

Comment: You can edit the question to add this code. Try to keep all the info on the Question post

Comment: You do know that "date before tomorrow" is "today", right?

Comment: Yes @Andreas, I know

Comment: Thx @areus, yesterday I wasn't able to edit the post

Comment: So why say "disable date before tomorrow" instead of just "disable today"? Or perhaps you misspoke and need to clarify the title of the question?

Comment: I have to build a project for an exam, and in that project I have to do a car sharing Application, with selectable dates. So I have to exclude the date before today (today included), to choose only reservation from tomorrow. That's why the date before tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry. All the dates before tomorrow, not only the date before tomorrow (so, today).